# Question on Android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Can I modify android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1? For eg., I want to change the text color of the textview inside the listview dynamically. For this, I need to get to the textview and change its color.. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom adapter class for your ListView. This way, you can create any UI layout for your list elements you like, and you can change their attributes dynamically. Here's a tutorial for this http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327